# Spring: redirect to home page once thread finishes its execution

Tags: spring

I am working on a project in spring in which there is a log in page and many other pages user can go to after logging in with correct credentials. When the user puts in the correct credentials and is allowed to go ahead I spawn a thread from the home controller (A requirement of what i am trying to achieve with this project). Since it is a thread it continues its execution and the controller returns a jsp to the user. The thread might take invariable time to finish but when it does the user has to be redirected back to the home page. To achieve this I thought I need to call a controller from the thread once it is over. But, it does not change the view.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an asynchronous job, u already lost the connection, committed the response. There is no such thing calling a controller from the thread.

One thing u can do, u can poll your server from client side with specific time intervals, ask whether the thread has done its job, if so redirect the user to the desired page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I thought about that but the problem with that is there are many pages in the project. Should i poll the thread from every page? Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: It depends on your visitor size. There are many other techniques that u can achiece this, but at the end of the day, they all do the same thing, in a more efficient way, with more tricks. If u have time, i suggest checking this out http://www.pushlets.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I shall go through it.